# Places API autocomplete problems

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, kotlin, google-places-api

Hi I'm new to android and am setting up the autocomplete code for the places api. I was following the google dev instructions on their website and ran into a problem that I can't seem to find any answers on.

I can't seem to find any info on what i am supposed to put for ID and NAME on the first line. There are no auto complete suggestions that come up and I haven't been able to find any info on it on the official documentation. I believe I have imported everything that I need to as I don't have any errors anywhere else in the code.

This is the guide I am following. I am in the section to add the autocomplete by using an intent. https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete

```
val location = findViewById<View>(R.id.location_button)
    location.setOnClickListener {
        val fields = listOf(Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT.ID,Place.TYPE_RESTAURANT.NAME)
        val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
            AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields).build(this)
        startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, the possible reason for not showing up the results is wrong use of API key or you probably have not activated the Places API in google console for the selected project/API key.

Comment: What does the logcat says when you click that location_button ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Place.Field`](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/model/Place.Field) as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#create_an_autocomplete_intent). Like this:

```
val fields = listOf(Place.Field.ID,Place.Field.NAME)
```

Hope this helps!